# Kb values of N,N-dimethylaniline derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, reference-request

I need the $K_\mathrm{b}$ values for *ortho-*, *meta-* and *para-* positions of the following compounds:

[image: Compounds list]

I've looked and couldn't find them anywhere.

Comment: I've redrawn the compounds of interest with [`chemfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) to make them more readable. However, I'm not sure I recognized all groups correctly — feel free to proof-read the edit. $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ source code is available at [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/unK86fHC).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[chemicalize.com](https://chemicalize.com) is  a cheminformatics website which is the kind of resource you are looking for.

You can use the search tool to find your compounds. The input is the structure itself, which you can draw in-situ.

Here is the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ data I retrieved from the aforementioned site. Note that these are **calculated / estimated**, not measured $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values.

[image]

**Table 1.** $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values (of the conjugate acid)

$$
\begin{array}{lccccc}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\textit{ortho-} & 3.71 & 5.19 & -0.98 & 1.44 & 2.66 \\
\textit{meta-} & 3.89 & 5.15 & 1.73 & 4.77 & 3.45 \\
\textit{para-} & 5.55 & 5.46 & 0.65 & 4.68 & 3.65 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Since the question is asking for $K_\mathrm{b}$ values, I converted them too.

**Table 2.** $K_\mathrm{b}$ values

$$
\begin{array}{lccccc}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\textit{ortho-} & \pu{5.13e-11} & \pu{1.55e-9} & \pu{1.05e-15} & \pu{2.75e-13} & \pu{4.57e-12} \\
\textit{meta-} & \pu{7.76e-11} & \pu{1.41e-9} & \pu{5.37e-13} & \pu{5.89e-10} & \pu{2.82e-11} \\
\textit{para-} & \pu{3.54e-9} & \pu{2.88e-9} & \pu{4.47e-14} & \pu{4.79e-10} & \pu{4.47e-11} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Please be kind enough to explain your downvote.